# create arrays from for loop output

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong here, but can't seem to determine the cause. I would like to create a set of arrays from an output for a for loop in bash. Below is the code I have so far:

```
for i in `onedatastore list | grep pure02 | awk '{print $1}'`; 
do 
     arr${i}=($(onedatastore show ${i} | sed 's/[A-Z]://' | cut -f2 -d\:)) ; 
     echo "Output of arr${i}: ${arr${i}[@]}" ; 
done
```

The output for the condition is as such:

```
107
108
109
```

What I want to do is based on these unique IDs is create arrays:

```
arr107
arr108
arr109
```

The arrays will have data like such in each:

```
[oneadmin@opennebula/]$ arr107=($(onedatastore show 107 | sed 's/[A-Z]://' | cut -f2 -d\:))
[oneadmin@opennebula/]$ echo ${arr107[@]}
DATASTORE 107 INFORMATION 107 pure02_vm_datastore_1 oneadmin oneadmin 0 IMAGE vcenter vcenter /var/lib/one//datastores/107 FILE READY DATASTORE CAPACITY 60T 21.9T 38.1T - PERMISSIONS um- u-- --- DATASTORE TEMPLATE CLONE_TARGET="NONE" DISK_TYPE="FILE" DS_MAD="vcenter" LN_TARGET="NONE" RESTRICTED_DIRS="/" SAFE_DIRS="/var/tmp" TM_MAD="vcenter" VCENTER_CLUSTER="CLUSTER01" IMAGES
```

When I try this in the script section though I get output errors as such:

```
./test.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `$(onedatastore show ${i} | sed 's/[A-Z]://' | cut -f2 -d\:)'
```

I can't seem to figure out the syntax to use on this scenario.

In the end what I want to do is be able to compare different datastores and based on which on has more free space, deploy VMs to it.

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: Which specific version of bash?

Comment: Be sure to read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `eval` (potentially unsafe) and `declare` (safer) commands:

```
for i in $(onedatastore list | grep pure02 | awk '{print $1}'); 
do 
    declare "arr$i=($(onedatastore show ${i} | sed 's/[A-Z]://' | cut -f2 -d\:))"
    eval echo 'Output of arr$i: ${arr'"$i"'[@]}'
done
```

Comment: Right now, this is potentially prone to security bugs, because it's double-evaluating the outputs of the inner command substitution. That command substitution should be escaped to only run *after* `eval` is invoked, not *before*.

Comment: BTW, if you're targeting bash 4.3, accessing `arr$i` is easy using namevars. Same for writing, for that matter.

Comment: To be clear, `eval 'arr'"$i"'=($(onedatastore show ${i} | sed "s/[A-Z]://" | cut -f2 -d\:))'` is an example of a safer version. (It's still buggy because it's using string-splitting to form an array, and so expanding globs without a user requirement to do so, but that's a whole different issue).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. `declare` clearly is the better option. The answer was updated.

Comment: Thx for this. Fixing not only the issue with the array creation, but also fixing what Charles pointed out as a security issue and using declare. This fixed the output of the echo as I was having issue with a substition error.

Answer (score 0):

`readarray` or `mapfile`, added in bash 4.0, will read directly into an array:

```
while IFS= read -r i <&3; do
  readarray -t "arr$i" < <(onedatastore show "$i" | sed 's/[A-Z]://' | cut -f2 -d:)
done 3< <(onedatastore list | awk '/pure02/ {print $1}')
```

---

Better, back through bash 3.x, one can use `read -a` to read to an array:

```
shopt -s pipefail # cause pipelines to fail if any element does

while IFS= read -r i <&3; do
  IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a "arr$i" \
    < <(onedatastore show "$i" | sed 's/[A-Z]://' | cut -f2 -d: && printf '\0')
done 3< <(onedatastore list | awk '/pure02/ {print $1}')
```

---

Alternately, one can use namevars to create an alias for an array with an arbitrarily-named array in bash 4.3:

```
while IFS= read -r i <&3; do
  declare -a "arr$i"
  declare -n arr="arr$i"
  # this is buggy: expands globs, string-splits on all characters in IFS, etc
  # ...but, well, it's what the OP is asking for...
  arr=( $(onedatastore show "$i" | sed 's/[A-Z]://' | cut -f2 -d:) )
done 3< <(onedatastore list | awk '/pure02/ {print $1}')
```

Comment: I like this answer as well. Only issue was trying to get the output done as I will need to compare fields within each array to determine which datastore is least used. I will +1 this just because you provided mechanisms for bash 3.x and below even though it wasn't asked and I was not explicit in my question.